# AJAX in Wordpress, sending coords data to MySQL and show after into map

Tags: php, ajax, mysql, google-maps

I've spent some months trying to figure out how to get users geolocation and pass it into MySQL and so after being shown with markers on the map. I've got stuck already in passing the data through ajax to php. And have search and research and also asked in stackoverflow. And as it seems my code is correct.

It seems that AJAX has a special way to work with WORDPRESS.

Here the code that exists in `template-maps.php`:

```
  var pos;
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
            map.setCenter(pos);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data:  { action : 'my_action', pos : pos},
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
            });
        },
        function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    };
```

What I have to write with the WordPress Codex to make my AJAX work?

Here the changes that I've made so far, creating a plugin for add `function my_function ()`:

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_function' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_function' );

    $translation_array = array(
        'admin_uri' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ,
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'script-handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

    function my_function(){

         $lat = isset($_POST['pos']['lat']) ? $_POST['pos']['lat'] : null;
         $lng = isset($_POST['pos']['lng']) ? $_POST['pos']['lng'] : null;


       var_dump($_POST['pos']);

    }

?>
```

And here the Notice that I get from the plugin:

> Notice: wp_localize_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /.../wp-includes/functions.php on line 4146

and this one:

> Notice: Undefined index: pos in /.../wp-content/plugins/zaeplug-userslocation/zaeplug-userslocation.php on line 26 NULL

Comment: `wp_localize_script` does not belong inside your ajax handler, not sure what that's supposed to be doing there.

Comment: Should I put out of the function? I am sorry but I've tried in many ways and always get `pos NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't directly ping any PHP file inside your theme or plugin folder. It's not safe, and most importantly, will *almost* never work since you don't have access to WordPress's core.

Instead, create an Admin-Ajax handler and process your code there.

To create one, all you have to do is add these lines to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_function' );

function my_function(){
    // Your php code here
}
```

Now, alter your ajax request to ping the admin-ajax.php file:, and include the action in your data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data:  { action : 'my_action', pos : pos},
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
});
```

However, I suggest you use [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass the `admin_url()` to your Ajax function.

Let's say you have enqueued your JS file the following way:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_localization_function');
function my_localization_function(){
    // Enqueue your script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle', 'my-script-url' );
}
```

You then can localize it. Add this after you enqueue your script:

```
$translation_array = array(
    'admin_uri' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ,
);
wp_localize_script( 'script-handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```

Now, your Ajax call can be this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data:  { action : 'my_action', pos : pos},
    url: object_name.admin_uri
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Jack! Have made some tries and get `Notice: Undefined index: pos in /home/.../wp-content/plugins/zaeplug-userslocation/zaeplug-userslocation.php on line 20` now will make a brake because my eyes are near to explote.

Comment: I'm getting NULL `Notice: Undefined index: pos in /home/.../wp-content/plugins/zaeplug-userslocation/zaeplug-userslocation.php on line 21
NULL`

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the variable

Comment: Nothing, I wrote it without apostrophes and get the same notice. In `my_function()` have written the php from the `template-userslocation.php`. After trying to declare also the pos variable out of the conditional as `var pos;` get the same answer. Have changed `lat: position.coords.latitude,  lng: position.coords.longitude` to real coordinates like: `lat: 43.362344, lng: -8.411540` and stil get `NULL`. Thank you for your support Jack.

Comment: Added the changes that I've done to the question. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Jack I've made some changes in my code, been reading the Codex from `wp_localize_script` but I`m still confused... I`ve refreshed the question with the new code and notices. :(